# I can't use "or loop with mutate(). Warning In 1:yrs : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, dplyr

Created a function for some calculations which worked fine on its own.
However, when I used it in `mutate()`, it seems to take all values from the column as input and ended with a warning message:
`In 1:yrs : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used`

```
library(dplyr)

mortgage <- function(amt = 800000, yrs = 25, mthly = 3630,  ints = 0.026) {
  yearPay <- mthly * 12
  paid <- 0
  remain <- amt
  for(i in 1:yrs) {
    paid = paid + yearPay
    remain = (amt - paid) * (1 + ints)
  }
  return(remain*-1)
}


tibble(loanAmt = c(800000, 800000, 800000, 700000, 700000, 700000),
                    period = c(15,20,25,15,20,25),
                    monthly = c(5373, 4279, 3630, 4701, 3744, 3176),
                    interest = 0.026) %>%
  mutate(credit = mortgage(loanAmt, period, monthly, interest))
```

I am trying to run the function mortgage() with data from each row, but mutate() seems to be taking all the values from `period` as a vector into the argument.

Can someone please show me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: first warning is `as_tibble` on a vector.  You can directly use `tibble`

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. You do in fact get a column of credit values; that wouldn't be the case if it were an error. But it's unclear what you expect to get—it seems like you're assigning arguments not in the order you intend. You've given a vector of length 6 to the argument `yrs`, so then `for(i in 1:yrs)` doesn't make sense, and that's where the warning comes from

Comment: @akrun thank you for the suggestion, I changed it, but the warning is still there and not working at I expected it to be.

Comment: @camille Indeed the warning is not working as expected.
What I wanted to do was to run `mortgage()` which data from each column for each row. For the first row it is fine, since it is using the first element. However, at the second row, I was hoping it to run `mortgage(800000, 20, 4279, 0.026)`. The third row should be `mortgage(800000, 25,3630,0.026)` and so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific issue you could use `dplyr::rowwise`:

```
x1=tibble(loanAmt = c(800000, 800000, 800000, 700000, 700000, 700000),
       period = c(15,20,25,15,20,25),
       monthly = c(5373, 4279, 3630, 4701, 3744, 3176),
       interest = 0.026) %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(credit = mortgage(loanAmt, period, monthly, interest))
x1
```

This is because a `for` loop is not vectorized. Though, keep in mind that using `rowwise` is grouping by each line, so it can be slow if your dataset is large.

However, your function seems to be simplifiable to this one, which does not need a `for` loop:

```
mortgage2 <- function(amt, yrs, mthly,  ints) {
  remain = (amt - mthly * 12 * (yrs)) * (1 + ints)
  return(remain*-1)
}

x2=tibble(loanAmt = c(800000, 800000, 800000, 700000, 700000, 700000),
       period = c(15,20,25,15,20,25),
       monthly = c(5373, 4279, 3630, 4701, 3744, 3176),
       interest = 0.026) %>%
  mutate(credit = mortgage2(loanAmt, period, monthly, interest))
x2
all(x1$credit==x2$credit) # TRUE :-)
```

Thus, no need for `rowwise` then.

Comment: Thanks! This worked really nicely! This is my first time hearing about `rowwise()`, it really does the trick for this issue. The new function worked too, I must have overthink it. >< Thanks a lot!